# What is the difference between c1 and c2 in the below program, are both declarations same?

Tags: java, wrapper

i have confusion between c1 and c2. Are both objects?

```
class demo
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        char c='w';
        Character c1=c;
        Character c2=new Character(c);
        System.out.println(c1);
        System.out.println(c2);
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, they are both objects.

Answer (score 3):

yes they are both objects, check out autoboxing.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

The compiler in this case converts `Character c1=c;` automatically in this

```
Character c1 = Character.valueOf(c)
```

**Edit to answer comment:**

They are not the same Objects (same hashcode), but they have the same value.

If you check out equals method in Character class you'll see that it overrides the default Object class equals, so that equality is true when their internal value is the same

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Character) {
        return value == ((Character)obj).charValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Okay that's fine but are both assignments of C1 and C2 same?

Answer (score 0):

They are both objects. However, let me explain you couple more things about it:

```
char c='w';
```

is a primitive value in Java (it represents a 16-bit Unicode value) and `Character c2=new Character(c);` is a wrapper class that could help you to use the char primitive in an OOP way.

Check out [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_characters.htm) to get a further explanation about `char` values